# possible use case of central limit theorem for analysts

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, central-limit-theorem

This is a bit of a long shot but I would appreciate any help please.

I have to do a basic stats course for our analysts, which I try to make as applicable and useful as possible using our data (e.g. showing skewed distributions and promoting the median over the arithmetic mean - basic stuff). Our analysts deal mainly with observational data but AFIK they never have to estimate the population mean of some external process. This is one of the main applications of the CLT. I am looking for any other use case for our analysts and would appreciate a possible example. We will later on also talk about bootstrapping, which is somewhat related but I want to keep it simple for now.

PS:

I think my main issue is, that we do not have a population and samples from it. Internally we have processes and we may want to compare process A vs process B. However, I would use bootstrapping for this. I just cannot see the direct application for CLT as we never intentionally collect several samples from a population ....

Comment: Could you please give a concrete example of your work. It is a widespread misconception especially in the e-commerce field  that you cannot use t-tests etc if your data is not normally distributed. However, companies are typically not interested in single value performance, but in totals ( total revenue etc). In this case averages are what you are interested in testing, and assuming your sample is large enough the central limit theorem basically covers you and enables you to use standard z-test/t-test/linear regression tests and no bootstrapping is necessary. So what is your sample size?

Comment: I believe you have a misunderstanding about the CLT. It is used to justify that the average of a *single* sample ( of say 100 widgets) is approximately normally distributed.

Comment: @seanv507 My understanding of the CLT is that you take several samples from a population. Each sample contains let us say 30 data points/rows. You then calculate your statistics for each sample (e.g. mean). The distribution of this statistics is approximately normal. So the mean of the means is a good estimate of the population mean. Not sure what you think I misunderstand? The issue I have is that we do not deliberately obtain several samples from some population/process. So I am struggling to find an application in my setting.

Comment: @seanv507 I understand what you say about the t-test etc. However, if your data is just ONE sample of an external population and you then pretend that it is a population and do CLT on let us say 2 levels of your ONE sample is the result useful? I know we deal with observational data so any insights are potentially dodgy anyway.

Comment: What I am saying is that you take a single sample of 30 data points, and calculate the sample mean. Because of CLT, that sample average *can* be approximately normal, so you can use z/t test. You don't need mean of means.  You can investigate how close the (single)  sample mean is to being normal by running bootstraps,calculating sample mean from each bootstrap sample. (You do that once, and then happily use standard t test until process changes dramatically)

Comment: Tldr: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem tells you a single sample mean is normally distributed. Just as if I tell you process X is normally distributed (known mean, as), then you can do a  z test on a single observation..

Comment: @seanv507 sure but would I not require several samples from the population of process A and B each in order to do some parametric test? Otherwise one sample from each of size, let us say 30, would be enough, which I doubt.

Comment: Yes the CLT is saying you only need a single sample of (30?) to do parametric test on sample mean.(whether 10 is sufficient or 100 is not specified), but see any demo such as http://onlinestatbook.com/stat_sim/sampling_dist/

Comment: The demo shows that histogram of eg 10,000 samples of the sample mean of eg 10 points look very like a normal, but to do a parametric test, you don't need to estimate the full distribution,just mean and variance of your sample,and then can calculate distribution of sample mean.

Answer (score 1):

The CLT allows to talk about the asymptotic distribution of the mean, which is useful for providing inference on it. For example, that an experiment has led to a change in the mean of group A vs group B. It is true that for right-tailed distribution it is more convenient (IMHO) to talk about the median instead, but making inference on the median is harder (e.g.: requires bootstrapping). In such cases, the CLT can be useful since if a transformation of the data (e.g.: log) will make the data approximately normal, then using a t-test on the log-transformed data will be allow us to make inference on a difference in medians in the original scale. Note, though, that the inference in such a case will be on the ratio of the medians, and not their difference.

The benefit here is that the queries for running such analysis are easily available in many SQL implementations (E.g.: Presto), and even excel. While bootstrapping requires getting the data to a more advanced environment such as R or Python.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your post. I do not think we run experiments. I think my main problem is, that we do not really have samples from a population. So producing a distribution of means, which will be normal under CLT, is an issue. I may just revert back to coins and stuff but I feel that makes it less accessible.

Comment: Bootstrapping makes the same "process" assumptions as CLT that you seem to want to avoid, so there is no help there. The main issue is, why avoid "process"? I bet if you describe your scientific scenario more clearly, the "process" interpretation will become relevant. After all, science concerns processes.

Comment: @BigBendRegion thanks. I guess if I have a process A and a process B and I run them long enough, the collected data represent to populations. I could then draw samples from each process, calculate some stats and perform test?

Comment: I'm not clear on why it is useful to discuss a method that works in the limit, when our datasets are finite.  The CLT can produce arbitrarily bad confidence intervals (tail non-coverage probabilities far from $\alpha/2$ for at least one of the confidence limits) when the raw data distribution is very asymmetric (e.g., when you didn't know to take logs).

Comment: I agree with Frank that neither CLT nor bootstrap solves the problem of skewness in finite samples. They both only tell you what happens with larger and larger samples. To understand how things work for your finite sample, use simulation.

Comment: @BigBendRegion thanks. I am sorry but what would be the difference between bootstrapping and simulation?

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks. I am aware of logging and how it makes a skewed distribution more normal (used log log models a lot for pricing in retail). However, are you saying that one should log a tailed distribution before CLT? This flies totally in the face of what everyone says about CLT AFIK. Namely, that the shape of the population distribution does not matter for CLT.

Comment: @BigBendRegion Looking at the folloing link. A simulation is the same as a sample from a population. My issue is that we do get data from a population over time but it may not be representative - link: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/252365_9e644bc0b58f4d7bb894630f06393929.html

Comment: @cs0815 the fact that the CLT bombs if you should have taken a symmetricizing transformation but didn't know to do that is the simplest explanation for why we should quit teaching the CLT in applied statistics courses.  It is a limit theorem.  It is of interest in _mathematical_ statistics.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I am sorry there may be a misunderstanding. I am perfectly aware of the log transformation in various contexts. What do you know about my distributions (-: They may be uniform - so symmetricizing transformation would not help. I may also deal with nominal variables like dices, coins or cards haha. If I read the last part of your comments correctly, CLT is more a theoretical concept?

Comment: Yes.  The only advantage of applying the CLT in practice is that you are supposed to not have to know the data distribution.  But that is a mirage.